# Unable to validate child nodes with Firebase security

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'm clearly missing some fundamental aspect of firebase security, because this shouldn't work.  I would expect it to throw a validation error when attempting to push invalid data.  (Inserting a new node into /nodes)

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "nodes": {
      ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'google'",
      ".write": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'google'",
      "user": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
      },
      "ts": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() <= now && newData.val() >= (now-1000*60*60*24)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my console I try to intentionally insert invalid data:

```
ref.child('nodes').push({
  'user': 'abc',
  'ts': 123
}, function(err){console.log(err);});
```

Which logs null, and when I check my database it was inserted, no validation errors!  I know I've got something fundamentally wrong, because a validation rule right after the .read and .write rows of the following disallows any writing. `.validate": "newData.hasChildren(['user', 'ts'])",`

```
{
  "nodes" : {
    "-KAgH0BLneWfGu8NymBo" : {
      "ts" : 123,
      "user" : "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops.  Missing "$node_id"

```
{
  "rules": {
    "nodes": {
       "$node_id":{
         ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'google'",
         ".write": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'google'",
         "user": {
           ".validate": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
         },
         "ts": {
           ".validate": "newData.val() <= now && newData.val() >= (now-1000*60*60*24)"
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back Benjamin. It is indeed a common mistake to miss the wildcard/$ variable in there.